# "Item does not take parameters" when filtering RDD - scala, Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, parameters, rdd

I am working with a csv file in Apache Spark. I created the RDD and I want to obtain separate RDDs for each month, so I am filtering by the date, which is expressed as 201601, 201602, etc...

```
case class Item(date: String, id: String, classification: String, description: String, algoIndex: String, stratumIndex: String, itemIndex: String, allGmIndex: String, gmRaIndex: String, coicopWeight: String, itemWeight: String, cpihCoicopWeight: String)

val quarter1 = sc.textFile ("examples/Q1.csv")

val q1 = quarter1 map {i => {
        val x = i.split(",")
        Item(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8), x(9), x(10), x(11))
        }
    }

val Jan = q1.filter {x=> x(0) == "201601"}
val Feb = q1.filter {x=> x(0) == "201602"}
val Mar = q1.filter {x=> x(0) == "201603"}
```

The last three lines cause the error "Item does not take parameters", in relation to the following bit:

```
{x=> x(0) == ..}
```

How can I fix this? What did I do wrong in my class?
Thank you a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

You use a case class, so you cannot use `apply` syntax. Use the names you defined:

```
q1.filter { x => x.date == "201601" }
```

or

```
q1.filter { _.date == "201601" }
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!
:)

Comment: although there is no `apply`, this is also possible with case-classes: `q1.filter {x => x.productElement(0) == "201601"}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `x`s in the function literals are of type `Item`.
`Item` does not have an `apply(i: Int)` method.
Instead, `Item` has a bunch of named member variables.

Try something like this instead:

```
val Jan = q1.filter {x => x.date == "201601"}
```

It can be abbreviated to:

```
val Jan = q1.filter (_.date == "201601")
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! :)